# How to pass output of grep to "lsof -p"?

Tags: bash, grep, command-line-arguments

I want to know the path of currently running `./a.out`

There are several MPI process, but I only need one of the PID of several `./a.out`. So I first use below code to grep it:

```
ps aux | grep -P "Rl.*a\.out" | grep -oP "\d+"|head -n 1
```

which gives one PID, for example 12345.

Now I want to use:

```
lsof -p12345
```

To know the file path of PID 12345.

How to combine the two-step into one command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the command that you need:

```
ps aux|grep -P "Rl.*a\.out"|grep -oP "\d+"|head -n 1 | xargs lsof -p
```

The key here is `xargs`.

Commands such as `grep` and `awk` can accept the *[standard input](http://www.linfo.org/standard_input.html)* (STDIN) as a parameter, or argument by using a pipe. However, others such as `cp`, `echo` and `lsof` disregard the standard input stream and rely solely on the *arguments* found after the command.

Using the command [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) you can build and execute command lines from standard input.

Comment: `pgrep -f "Rl.*a\.out" | paste -sd, | xargs lsof -p` would be more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `xargs` when a command returns multiple lines (or records). In this case, the command returns a single PID and a shell feature known as [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) would be an appropriate solution.

This allows the output of one command to be used by another and is accomplished by wrapping the command that provides the input in `$(` and `)`. In the past, backticks (`) were used but these are no longer recommended.

```
lsof -p $(ps aux|grep -P "Rl.*a\.out"|grep -oP "\d+"|head -n 1)
```

Comment: I just learned $() yesterday, but forgot to use it here.... Thank you very much

Comment: For multiple matches this works too: `lsof -p $(pgrep -d, spotify)`; where `pgrep -d,` lists all matching PIDs separated by comma that `lsof` enjoys. For single matches, you could also use `pgrep -n` for newest or `pgrep -o` for oldest if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st complex command to find the PID based on name can be replaced by `pgrep`, e.g.

```
$ pgrep -nf a.out
70512
```

Then to get the path from `lsof`, you can use conditional print in `awk`.

So the command could be:

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep -nf a.out) | awk '$4 == "cwd" {print $9}'
```

Above is based on the following `lsof` output:

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep -nf a.out)
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
gsleep  70513 kenorb  cwd    DIR    1,4      1938 121793972 /my/path
```

Comment: I really like your answser. `pgrep` combined with `awk` is so handy for this kind of task. Thank you very much